# QRegExp to find nth character NOT in a HTML tag

Tags: regex, qt, qregexp

Lets say I have a string such as this:

```
<span class='hi'>Blah <span class='bye'> is here </span> and here</span>
```

And I want to get the index in the string of the 7th character that isn't part of a HTML tag (the "i"). I know I'll be able to do this by splitting and iterating over the chunks, but I'm wondering if there is a QRegExp that I can use to do it. I've tried a bunch of stuff running using regexp.indexIn():

```
QRegExp r("[^<](?!>)"); // Matches index 1 
QRegExp r("[^<](?![^>])"); // Matches index 15 (the ' within the first span)
QRegExp r("[^<](.){7}(?!>)"); // Matches index 1
QRegExp r("^<.>[^<](?!>).{7}"); // Gives me -1
```

Is there a regexp that can do this (generically)?

Answer (score 0):

rxIt isn't generally considered a good idea to parse HTML using regex but many people do it. Could you try a replace instead?

```
QRegExp rx("<[^>]*>");
QString example = "<span class='hi'>Blah <span class='bye'> is here </span> and here</span>";
example.replace(rx, "");
```

And then find the 7th character? using:

```
example.at(7);
```

Comment: Yeh, I realise it's not ideal, but it's a lot less computational work than parsing to DOM or something like that (or is it?). The problem is that I want to insert a span at a particular point, so we'd have to then put all those removed spans back. So I was hoping to get the regexp to essentially translate to the index so I could bang a span in at that point. I can also just use a loop to do it.